# Could not load PNG in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl2

I have three image files, one is Techs.png, one is Techs.gif and one is Techs.bmp. I have used SDL_image 2.0.5 and SDL 2. When I load the image of Techs.gif and Techs.bmp, there is no error, but when I load the image of Techs.png.
SDL_Surface*Surface=IMG_Load("Techs.png"), an error occurs, I cannot load this image and Surface always returns NULL, I am using Visual Studio 2019.
Can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: That Error is Surface of this Image is always returns NULL and i cann't load it to the screen.

Comment: Ok, what error message do you get? Or are you meaning that you don't get an error message, that the returned value is always nullptr?

Comment: Also, can we assume that you [read the doc](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_11.html) and used `IMG_GetError()` to get the error message?

Comment: I tried that way before, the error message is "Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Thanks, i  just copied only "SDL_image.dll" from lib folder of SDL_image to my project. Therefore i get an error .

Comment: _"Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: The specified module could not be found."_ Did you also copy libpng16-16.dll?

Comment: At that time I forgot to copy it to my project, Now I have copied it to my project and I can load my image. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answer I posted, you may want to add a full answer detailing what the error actually was and how you managed to fix it. This would help greatly the future visitors that come here with this issue.

Comment: Oh, the error is because I forgot to add the file "libpng16-16.dll" to my project, so I got this error.

Comment: Yes; since users scroll down to answers and not comments, they'll most likely miss it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, make sure you [read the documentation](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_11.html) for the functions you use. There are sometimes hidden gems and very useful tips there.

In this case, we can see that there is a function called [`IMG_GetError()`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_45.html) which should be used to retrieve a human readable message of the error you got.

Using this, you'll be able to narrow down the possible sources of issues.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Traistorm For future users, it might be helpful to mention what the problem was. I imagine its that SDL does not support loading `png` files by default and you had to use the `SDL_Image` extention? It would be good for this to be mentioned somewhere.